# Full-width background color inside a div

Tags: css, colors, html

I've got a simple div that holds lines of text that have an alternating background color. The first line is green, second is red, third is green and so on. This div is 450px wide and most of the lines of text don't span the whole length of the div, but I'd like the background color to span the full 450px from left to right.

I've tried adding width: 450px to the span tag for the text, but still can't get it to go across all the way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `display: block` on your span elements, the background color should span the full width of its container.

When you use `display: block` property for span elements they will be shown as a block, that is, the line break at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: block` on the span element

See this jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YJS9c/)